# How do I prevent my HTML button from refreshing the entire page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I built a simple sentence generator -- when you click an HTML button, a random sentence is generated beneath it.

However, each time you click the button, the whole page refreshes. How can I prevent that, and simply refresh the sentence below the button?

Here's the button HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">

<center><button onclick="location.reload()">Click me</button></center>

</div>
```

and the HTML where the sentence appears:

```
<div class="container">

<h5></h5>

</div>
```

Lastly, here's the script that generates the sentence (not sure if it's relevant):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    //declare arrays
    var nouns = ['noun 1', 'noun 2']; 
    var clauses = ['clause 1'];
    var names = ['name 1','name 2'];   
    var adjective = ['adjective 1'];    
    var reasons = ['reason 1'];    
    //shuffle through contents of each array, picking one entry per  array
    var randNoun = nouns[Math.floor(Math.random() * nouns.length)];
    var randName = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
    var randClause = clauses[Math.floor(Math.random() * clauses.length)];
    var randScandal = scandals[Math.floor(Math.random() * scandals.length)];
    var randReason = reasons[Math.floor(Math.random() * reasons.length)];
    //place the random entry into the appropriate place in the HTML
    jQuery("h5").html("");
    jQuery("h5").append(randNoun + "&nbsp;");
    jQuery("h5").append(randClause + "&nbsp;");
    jQuery("h5").append(randName + "&nbsp;");
    jQuery("h5").append(randScandal + "&nbsp;");
    jQuery("h5").append(randReason);

});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Um, why are you doing `onclick="location.reload()"`? Losing that will stop your page from reloading. And on an unrelated note, the `<center>` element doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: You might as well want to accept one of the answers if your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the code in a function:

```
function generate(){
    //declare arrays
    var nouns = ['noun 1', 'noun 2']; 
    var clauses = ['clause 1'];
    var names = ['name 1','name 2'];   
    var adjective = ['adjective 1'];    
    var reasons = ['reason 1'];    
    //shuffle through contents of each array, picking one entry per  array
    var randNoun = nouns[Math.floor(Math.random() * nouns.length)];
    var randName = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
    var randClause = clauses[Math.floor(Math.random() * clauses.length)];
    var randScandal = scandals[Math.floor(Math.random() * scandals.length)];
    var randReason = reasons[Math.floor(Math.random() * reasons.length)];
    //place the random entry into the appropriate place in the HTML
    jQuery("h5").html("");
    jQuery("h5").append(randNoun + "&nbsp;");
    jQuery("h5").append(randClause + "&nbsp;");
    jQuery("h5").append(randName + "&nbsp;");
    jQuery("h5").append(randScandal + "&nbsp;");
    jQuery("h5").append(randReason);
}
```

Then call that function on button click
HTML:

```
<center><button>Click me</button></center>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('button').on('click', function(){
      generate();
      //or you can have all the code here without a function
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply put the entire jquery code in a function, the `onclick="location.reload()` on your code loads the entire page. Remove it.-

```
 <script>  function sentenceLoad() {
                //declare arrays
var nouns = ['noun 1', 'noun 2']; 
var clauses = ['clause 1'];
var names = ['name 1','name 2'];   
var adjective = ['adjective 1'];    
var reasons = ['reason 1'];    
//shuffle through contents of each array, picking one entry per  array
var randNoun = nouns[Math.floor(Math.random() * nouns.length)];
var randName = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
var randClause = clauses[Math.floor(Math.random() * clauses.length)];
var randScandal = scandals[Math.floor(Math.random() * scandals.length)];
var randReason = reasons[Math.floor(Math.random() * reasons.length)];
//place the random entry into the appropriate place in the HTML
jQuery("h5").html("");
jQuery("h5").append(randNoun + "&nbsp;");
jQuery("h5").append(randClause + "&nbsp;");
jQuery("h5").append(randName + "&nbsp;");
jQuery("h5").append(randScandal + "&nbsp;");
jQuery("h5").append(randReason);

 }
    </script>
```

In the html, replace the button with-

```
  <button onclick="sentenceLoad()">Click me!</button>
```